# how to return a list from python to webpage

Tags: python, flask

So, I am using flask and I have some lines of code written that will store some values in a list. I want to display these values in the list on a web page and I have done the following:

```
#Python code  to generate values for the list
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    list1 = ['a', 'b']
    return render_template("main1.html", var=list1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If i run the following program, a bunch of errors are displayed and it says Internal Server Error on the webpage. Any inputs regarding how I can display the list on the web page will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you include the error that gets displayed in your question?

Comment: You should also include:(1) folder structure (2) content of main1.html

Comment: [2017-02-21 14:02:00,308] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\apabhishek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

Comment: my main1.html contains <html>
<head>
<title> Config Parser</title>
</head>
{% for i in var %}
<p>{{i}}</p>
{% endfor %}
</html>

Comment: Please _edit_ your question, don't post errors as comment, and add the _full_ stack trace, not only the first stack trace element.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `render_template`,flask will look for templates in the `templates` folder,this folder is next to that module.So your package should be like this:

```
/app.py
/templates
    /main1.html
```

If `main1.html` does not exist,you can't visit the web page,here is an example.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
{% for i in list1 %}
        <h2>{{ i }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

See more details from [rendering-templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates)  .

Comment: the html file is in the templates folder

Comment: @AbhishekA.P  It works for me,please edit your question and include the errors.